# OpenSSH does not start

Tags: ssh, openssh

I experience a problem with OpenSSH on my Raspberry Pi. SSH service does not start anymore. The following error occurs:

```
$ sudo systemctl status ssh.service
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server Loaded: loaded (lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: signal) since Mon 2021-05-03 07:44:27 CEST; 20s ago Process: 12924 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 
Mai 03 07:44:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart. Mai 03 07:44:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5. 
Mai 03 07:44:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped
OpenBSD Secure Shell server. Mai 03 07:44:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly. Mai 03 07:44:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'signal'. 
Mai 03 07:44:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

When I test my config the following error occurs:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T
Memory access error
```

I tried to reinstall OpenSSH and created a new config but always the same problem.
Does somebody have an idea how I can fix this without reinstalling my whole Pi?

Comment: Are you running some memory intensive application on this Pi?

Comment: which model pi? which version of Raspberry Pi OS? did you recently apt upgrade?

Comment: No only WireGuard is running there.
Raspberry Pi 3B, Raspberry Pi OS Lite 2021-01-11

Comment: Is your memory OK? Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install memtester; sudo memtester 500 10` to verify? Can you put `OPTIONS="-ddd" ` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: There are a number of problems with ssh and Wireguard. Is it possible to stop wireguard? Does sshd start when Wireguard is stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a restart my Pi didn't boot anymore so I tried another micro SD card and reinstalled it. The old card was pretty much broken because. I tried to access it with my Ubuntu notebook but there was nothing readable on it.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

is the message a copy and paste or is it handwritten?
Because I see that **systemd** is still written **sysetmd** which is weird....the name of the folder is maybe wrongly named?

Comment: Sorry I could only connect via Console that's why it's handwritten.

Comment: ok I understand, could you place this order?
df -h to see if there is space on the sd